# Episerver upgrade 6 to episerver 7 error

Tags: episerver, episerver-6

Hi i am trying to upgrade EPiSERVER 6 website to EPiSERVER 7 through EPiSERVER deployment center. I am keep getting this error hope some one will able to help me out here.

**Error - Method invocation failed because [System.String] doesn't contain a method named 'get_Attributes'.**

Details:

At C:\Program Files (x86)\EPiServer\CMS\7.0.586.1\Upgrade\System Scripts\Upgrade Site To 7 (SqlServer).ps1:258 char:89
+   foreach ($attribute in $webConfigDoc.configuration.episerver.virtualPath.get_Attributes <<<< ())
System.Management.Automation.ParentContainsErrorRecordException: Method invocation failed because [System.String] doesn't contain a method named 'get_Attributes'.

Comment: What does your virtualPath config look like?